# Python: Method in subclasses that has different assignments

Tags: python

I have a method `run()` in subclasses, which has an API POST request in each subclass, gets data from the POST request, and assigns an ID from this data to `self._id`. Now I would like to get a description too. However, description is returned only in the API request `self._api_obj.trigger(...)` in `SubClassB.run`, not in the API request `self._api_obj.trigger_run(...)` in `SubClassA.run`. For `SubclassA` I need a separate API request to get the description.

I tried the following, but I don't think it's a good idea to assign 2 attributes in `SubClassB.run`, but only 1 attribute in `SubClassA.run`. Right? Since from my understanding, the same method in subclasses should have the same behavior (Just different implementation).

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = None  # Assigned in run()
        self._description = None

    @property
    def description(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def run(self, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id


class SubClassA(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._api_obj = ApiObj1()

    @property
    def description(self):
        if not self._description:
            _result = self._api_obj.get_data()
            self._description = _result["description"]
        return self._description

    def run(self, *args):
        _result = self._api_obj.trigger_run(foo="foo")
        self._id = _result["RunId"]


class SubClassB(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._api_obj = ApiObj2()

    @property
    def description(self):
        return self._description

    def run(self, *args):
        _result = self._api_obj.trigger(foo="foo", bar="bar", arg1="arg1", arg2="arg2")
        self._id = _result["data"]["id"]
        self._description = _result["data"]["description"]
```

Is there a better way to add assignment to `self._description`? Or some other solution to include description?

Comment: Why can't you just add the `result = ...` and `self._description = ...` lines from `SubclassA.description` to `SubclassA.run`?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi, It's a good idea. However, in external scripts, some scripts need description after `run()` and some do not. So if I add `self._description = ...` in `SubclassA.run`, then an external script will have an API request to get description, without needing it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I thought of: Creating a private method `_run()`, that will set and return the complete result of the run. The method `SubClassB.get_description()` will be able to get any required info from it. However, `SubClassA.get_description()` will get the description from the API.

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = None  # Assigned in run()
        self._run_result_info = None  # Assigned in _run()

    def _run(self, *args):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    def get_description(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id


class SubClassA(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._api_obj = ApiObj1()

    def _run(self):
        self._run_result_info = self._api_obj.trigger_run(foo="foo")
        return self._run_result_info

    def run(self):
        _result = self._run()
        self._id = _result["RunId"]
        
    def get_description(self):
        _result = self._api_obj.get_data()
        _description = _result["description"]
        return _description


class SubClassB(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._api_obj = ApiObj2()

    def _run(self):
        self._run_result_info = self._api_obj.trigger(foo="foo", bar="bar", arg1="arg1", arg2="arg2")
        return self._run_result_info
    
    def run(self):
        _result = self._run()
        self._id = _result["data"]["id"]

    def get_description(self):
        return self._run_result_info["data"]["description"]
```

Another option: Not keeping the result of the run, since it's not always needed. Just have a property `description` that will get the description through an API request only in cases it's needed. It means that we will need an API request in `SubClassB` to get the description too, instead of having the data available after `SubClassB.run`, but at least we're not keeping unneeded data, if it's not requested. We keep it only if it's requested.

```
class SuperClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self._id = None  # Assigned in run()
        self._description = None

    @property
    def description(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def id(self):
        return self._id


class SubClassA(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._api_obj = ApiObj1()

    @property
    def description(self):
        if not self._description:
            _result = self._api_obj.get_data()
            self._description = _result["description"]
        return self._description

    def run(self, *args):
        _result = self._api_obj.trigger_run(foo="foo")
        self._id = _result["RunId"]


class SubClassB(SuperClass):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._api_obj = ApiObj2()

    @property
    def description(self):
        if not self._description:
            _result = self._api_obj.get_info()
            self._description = _result["description"]
        return self._description

    def run(self, *args):
        _result = self._api_obj.trigger(foo="foo", bar="bar", arg1="arg1", arg2="arg2")
        self._id = _result["data"]["id"]
```